# How can I link IOKit using theos?

Tags: ios, theos, iokit

I'm developing a tweak getting battery information using IOKit, but it fails to build.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo", referenced from:
      getBatteryPercent(int*) in PRJNAME.mm.3bb88719.o
  "_IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList", referenced from:
      getBatteryPercent(int*) in PRJNAME.mm.3bb88719.o
  "_IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription", referenced from:
      getBatteryPercent(int*) in PRJNAME.mm.3bb88719.o
```

I have already copied `libIOKit.dylib` into `$THEOS/lib/` and worked with makefile but it seems the dylib is not linked with.

How can I solve this?

Comment: irc.saurik.com #theos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by makefile of the subproject.

So my both makefile includes

`XXX_LDFLAGS = -lIOKit -L<Library directory, necessary if the dylib is not in $THEOS/lib>`

Thanks.